# React native Customize JitsiMeetView component

Tags: android, ios, react-native, webrtc, jitsi

I need to set feature flags on RNJitsiMeetModule to change options on JitsiMeetView component, I set them as shown above, but no changes persist, except SetFeatureFlag ("chat. enabled", false),  it works for, could anyone help me to disable some options?

> https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/mobile-feature-flags

```
RNJitsiMeetConferenceOptions options = new RNJitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
                            .setRoom(url)
                            .setAudioOnly(true)
                            .setUserInfo(_userInfo)
                            .setAudioOnly(false)
                            .setWelcomePageEnabled(false)
                            .setFeatureFlag("call-integration.enabled",false)
                            .setFeatureFlag("close-captions.enabled",false)
                            .setFeatureFlag("chat.enabled",false)
                            .build();
                    mJitsiMeetViewReference.getJitsiMeetView().join(options);
```